# A problem with me when registering on Github

Tags: github

I know that this is not the right place to post such a question or problem. But I have nobody else to ask. I am stuck with registering on Github because of this infinitely silly verification game. I have been verifying the email for more than one hour and the account is not yet verified. What can I do to come over this problem?. I provide a screenshot to better understand my problem.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: How long have you waited for the email? Sometimes it can take up to 8 hours.

Comment: 8 hours?!! Unbelievable. I just waited for 1 hour.

Comment: I don’t know if it’s intentional or not, but I’ve seen this issue before with both GitHub and GitLab. Perhaps it’s intentional to prevent scraping and automation, perhaps it’s a latency issue with their MFA. Have you received it yet?

Answer (score 0):

There was an incident ("[degraded performance for Git Operations](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/nkmhbfx8tgg7)") which could have has, as a side-effect, some issues on the registration process.

So if the issue persists, you might have to contact GitHub support.